# MySQL: Getting current row ID in update

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

So I'm working on this trigger that updates an account balance as soon as one of the transaction types logged on it is changed. Here is the query:

```
BEGIN

    IF (OLD.debit != NEW.debit) THEN

        UPDATE account,

      (SELECT accountid,
      sum(accountentry.amountaccountentry) AS total
      FROM accountentry
      WHERE accountentry.typeid = NEW.idaccounttype
      AND accountentry.accountid = account.idaccount
      GROUP BY accountentry.accountid) AS s
      SET account.balanceaccount = IF(NEW.debit = 1, IF(s.total IS NOT NULL, balanceaccount - s.total * 2, balanceaccount), IF(s.total IS NOT NULL, balanceaccount + s.total * 2, balanceaccount));
    
    END IF;

END
```

Now, this query does work if I remove the "AND accountentry.accountid = account.idaccount" part. Since I'm in some kind of "sub query", how would I go about retrieving the id of the account I'm currently updating?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: When you update in SQL, you can access the record you're updating just like in SQL SELECT. So, for example `UPDATE t1 SET c1 = x WHERE t1.c2 = y;` Not sure that answers your question though.

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing a sum over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the goal of keeping redundant data out of the database but I also understand that this is not always practical.  In this case, retrieving the balance by aggregating the transactions should be very low cost if appropriate indices are in place.  I do not know the details of your specific scenario but, at the very least, you should be very cautious when introducing redundant data.  It will almost certainly become inconsistent at some point.

Having this update in a trigger, as opposed to plainly visible in a transaction in your application's code, is a likely source of hard to track bugs in the future.

You have not included enough information (CREATE TABLE statements, sample data, desired outcome) in your question for me to answer with confidence but I will have a go.

Your update query appears to be attempting to handle the scenario where the transaction type for one entry is being changed from debit to credit or vice versa but it does not allow for the amountaccountentry changing at the same time.  I do not understand why you are using GROUP BY and SUM when you are only dealing with a change to one accountentry.  Surely you could use -

```sql
BEGIN

    IF (OLD.debit != NEW.debit AND OLD.amountaccountentry = NEW.amountaccountentry) THEN

        UPDATE account
        SET account.balanceaccount = IF(NEW.debit = 1, IF(NEW.amountaccountentry IS NOT NULL, balanceaccount - (NEW.amountaccountentry * 2), balanceaccount), IF(NEW.amountaccountentry IS NOT NULL, balanceaccount + (NEW.amountaccountentry * 2), balanceaccount))
        WHERE idaccount = NEW.accountid;
    
    END IF;

END
```

or if amountaccountentry could change at the same time -

```sql
BEGIN

    IF (OLD.debit != NEW.debit) THEN

        UPDATE account
        SET account.balanceaccount = IF(NEW.debit = 1, IF(NEW.amountaccountentry IS NOT NULL, balanceaccount - (OLD.amountaccountentry + NEW.amountaccountentry), balanceaccount), IF(NEW.amountaccountentry IS NOT NULL, balanceaccount + (OLD.amountaccountentry + NEW.amountaccountentry), balanceaccount))
        WHERE idaccount = NEW.accountid;
    
    END IF;

END
```

If I have completely misunderstood your issue, please update your question with the additional details mentioned above.